# Proving boundary of a set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $E ⊂ X$, we define the boundary of $E$, denoted $∂E$, to be the set of $x ∈ X$ such that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of both $E$ and $E^c$.

i) Prove that $E^◦ = E\setminus∂E$, and $E_1 = E ∪ ∂E$ .

ii) Prove that $∂E = E_1 ∩ (E_1^c)$, and hence that $∂E$ is closed.

i) seems intuitive to me, but I can't find a way to express it mathematically.  The interior points of E are the set E less the boundary of E is basically the definition. I don't understand how to show $∂E$ is closed.

($E_1$ is closed and $(X, d)$ is a nonempty metric space.)

Comment: ii) doesn't make sense. $E\cap E^c = \emptyset$.

Comment: The syntax is `\setminus` or  `\smallsetminus`.  There seems to be some closure notations missing in your formulae.

Comment: Also $E = E \cup \partial E$ iff $E$ is closed. You probably have forgotten some closure signs

Comment: It is important that **$E_1$ is the closure of $E$,** not any arbitrary closed set.

Answer (score 1):

The true formula for ii), is:
$$\partial E=\overline E\cap \overline{E^c}$$
Indeed this is the transcription of the definition of the boundary., which is thus the intersection of two closed sets.